# Help identifying some old chairs

Tags: joinery

I came across these old chairs for a very fair price.....free. I’m just wondering if anyone has ever seen this style. [image]

Comment: More pics would definitely help here! Also please note that although someone might want to be helpful and try to identify the wood for you wood IDs are off-topic for this SE.

Answer (score 1):

those chairs are a danish/midcentury modern style. The joint is a double bridle joint. refinish them and they will look very nice indeed.

Comment: Would you say the wood is walnut?

Comment: @Ajm9130 hard to tell. it's not NOT walnut... more pics would help, and better lighting. It's a little light, but walnut can get bleached over time.

Comment: When does a multiple bridle joint become a box joint?  Triple bridle?  Quadruple bridle?

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 when it's used for boxes!